# Why is this c++ multithreading mutex code exhibiting occasional failures?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I am using this foo.cpp code below on a linux Debian system:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cvar;
long next = 0;

void doit(long index){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  cvar.wait(lock, [=]{return index == next;});

  std::cout<< index << std::endl;
  ++next;

  mtx.unlock();
  cvar.notify_all();

  return;
}

int main() 
{
  long n=50;

  for (long i=0; i < n; ++i)
    std::thread (doit,i).detach();

  while(next != n)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

  return(0);
}
```

I compile it with:

g++ -std=c++14 -pthread -o foo foo.cpp

It is designed to fire off 50 threads, detached, which are controlled by a mutex and condition_variable in the function doit, so they execute the mutex block sequentially.

It works most of the time, writing the numbers 00 to 49 to the screen, and then terminating.

However, it has two occasional failure modes:

**Failure mode 1**: After going up to some arbitrary number < 50, it aborts with the error:

foo: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.

**Failure mode 2**: After going up to some arbitrary number < 50, it hangs, and has to be killed with ctrl-C to get back to the terminal prompt.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to the causes of this behavior, and how I can fix it.

=========================================================================

**Edit:** Ok, so here is a working revised version. I fixed the two bugs, and also changed the lock name from "lock" to "lk" to reduce confusion. Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cvar;
long next = 0;

void doit(long index){

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
  cvar.wait(lk, [=]{return index == next;});

  std::cout<< index << std::endl;
  ++next;

  lk.unlock();
  cvar.notify_all();

  return;
}

int main()
{
  long n=50;

  for (long i=0; i < n; ++i)
    std::thread (doit,i).detach();

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    cvar.wait(lk, [=]{return n == next;});
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(next != n)` attempts to access variable `next` that can be modified by working threads without any sync creating a race condition. It should be covered by the same mutex:

```
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
   cvar.wait(lock, [=]{return n == next;});
}
```

Detaching threads is not a good idea. You should store them somewhere and then `join` before returning from `main`.

Update: You are trying to call `unlock` on `mutex` itself instead of calling it on lock object. By constructing lock object you are delegating responsibility for unlocking mutex to `lock` object. It should be

```
lock.unlock();
cvar.notify_all();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion with the while(next != n) condition. Using the above lock/wait code however still leads to the same failure modes. I am curious why is detaching not a good idea in this context?

Comment: @Leo Detaching is not a good idea in general because you lose control over threads.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, this last update fixes it. That was clearly the bug, and it's consistent with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand detaching the threads, since you cannot join them after that.
If you really want to do it, then use condition variable to synchronize data for the while next.

```
void doit(long index){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  cvar.wait(lock, [=]{return index == next;});

  std::cout<< index << std::endl;
  ++next;

  cvar.notify_all();

  return;
}

int main() 
{
  long n=50;

  for (long i=0; i < n; ++i)
    std::thread (doit,i).detach();

  //here you wait for the last thread to finish
  {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
     cvar.wait(lock, [=]{return n == next;});
  }

  return(0);
}
```

If you can have your thread being joinable you can write simpler code.

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cvar;
long next = 0;

void doit(long index){
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

  //this guarantees the order in which are being executed
  cvar.wait(lock, [=]{return index == next;});

  std::cout<< index << std::endl;
  ++next;

  cvar.notify_all();//wakes all the thread, only the one with index=next will be executed

  return;
}

int main() 
{
    long n=50;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    for (long i=0; i < n; ++i){
      workers.emplace_back(std::thread (doit,i));
    }

    //this guarantees your threads are all finished at the end of this block
    for (auto& t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Being unable to join a thread is not always a bad thing.  Sometimes you don't _want_ to ever join a thread.

Comment: it depends what you want to do. Here the problem looks like a producer/consumer. Joining threads can be a good thing here

Comment: This example code could be written with joinable threads as suggested. However, the relevant code that brought this issue up for me is a server-side code running in a client-server environment. The server is running in an infinite loop, and, when it gets client-requested work to do, it fires up the requisite number of threads and goes back to listening for additional requests. The threads thus spun-off need to do some particular tasks following the order they were spun-off in, in the full-version of doit(), and then never need to be heard from again. Detaching them makes sense in this setting.

Comment: ok understood. I leave it with non detachable threads for other people that could look at the answer. If you're happy with the answer, upvote it to mark it as relevant

Answer (score -1):

Why not keep it simple?

```
int main() {
    long n = 50;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back([=]() { std::cout << i << std::endl; });

    for (const auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this solution would not guarantee the order of the execution of the threads.

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet: You shouldn't use mtx.unlock() and let the condition_variable do the job. Also use std::ref to pass the function parameter to the thread.

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cvar;
bool ready = true;

void doit(long index) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    cvar.wait(lock, [=] {return ready == true; });
    ready = false;
    std::cout << index << std::endl;

    ready = true;
    cvar.notify_all();

    return;
}

int main()
{
    long n = 50;

    for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::thread(doit, std::ref(i)).detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! removing mtx.unlock() did the trick. The above other changes would not work for me, as I need the threads to execute the mutex block in sequential order 0 1 2 ... 49. However, the problem is fixed by removing the mtx.unlock().

Comment: Why do you use `std::ref`?

Answer (score -1):

`std:: unique_lock` is an RAII object. Declare it in a scope and cast your cares to the wind. Here's the problem: After doit calls mtx.unlock(), occasionally the next statement cvar.notify_all() will immediately wake up the thread with (the new) next == index. That thread will acquire the mutex. When doit returns, the lock destructor attempts to release the mutex, but it's held by another thread. Disaster ensues. Here's how to doit():

```
void doit(long index) {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        cvar.wait(lock, [=] {return index == next; });
        ++next;
        std::cout << index << std::endl;
    }

    cvar.notify_all(); 

    return;
}
```